# "Pulling down" the elements of the 2D array to the blank spaces within the array

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, space

I am a beginner in C and I just wanted to create a simple program on CM-DOS that is like Bejewelled.

I am almost done with the coding but there is just ONE problem:

In Bejewelled, when the matches are found, the elements above those matches will replace the the empty spaces created by the matches (the so-called "Pull Down").

I am having trouble with it because the program just ignores my code for Pulling down and

just prints the empty space as is.

Please help?

My Program is 2D array of a[6][6].

Initialize(b); is a function that checks if the generated alphabet has any matches with the existing alphabets. If yes, then it will re-genrate the generated alphabet into another until
there is no match.

It basically fills the random alphabets from 'A' to 'D' into b[8][8] then converts b[8][8] into 
a[6][6] then prints grid.

Here is my problematic pulling down code:

```
void pull(char a[6][6], char b[8][8])
{
int j=0,i=0,loop=0;


while(loop){
for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
{
for (j = 1; j <= 5; j++)
{
if(a[i][j]==' ')
{
a[i][j]=a[i-1][j];
loop=1;
}
else if (a[i][j] == a[0][j])
{
a[i][j] = rand()%4 + 'A';
initialize(b);            
}
}   
}
}
}
```

This is what I want (For Example)

```
C   A   B   C   D   C

A   B   C   D   B   D

D   C   D   !A   A   A!  // Match Found

A   B   D   C   B   C

B   D   C   A   C   D

C   D   C   B   C   C
```

Then

```
C   A   B   C   D   C

A   B   C   D   B   D

D   C   D   ?   ?   ?  // ? = space

A   B   D   C   B   C

B   D   C   A   C   D

C   D   C   B   C   C
```

Then

```
C   A   B   C   D   C

A   B   C   ?   ?   ?  // ? = space gets swapped upward

D   C   D   D   B   D

A   B   D   C   B   C

B   D   C   A   C   D

C   D   C   B   C   C
```

And then

```
C   A   B   ?   ?   ?

A   B   C   C   D   C

D   C   D   D   B   D 

A   B   D   C   B   C

B   D   C   A   C   D

C   D   C   B   C   C
```

If the ? reaches the maximum height, it generates new random alphabets into ?

```
C   A   B   A*  C*  B* // *New Alphabets

A   B   C   C   D   C

D   C   D   D   B   D 

A   B   D   C   B   C

B   D   C   A   C   D

C   D   C   B   C   C
```

Comment: For an array of size **N**, valid array indexes are **0** to **N-1**.

Comment: The reason why I put i = 1 until i <= 5 is that I want the ? to be swapped upward until i = 0 then the code will go for my "else if" statement which will only work when i = 0

Answer (score 0):

```
void nomatch(char a[6][6])
{
int i, j,k;
int ini;

ini=0;
do {
for (k = 0; k < 7; k++)
{
for (i = 0; i < 7; i++) 
{
for (j = 0; j < 7; j++)
{
if (a[i][j] == a[i+1][j] && a[i+1][j] == a[i+2][j]) 
{
a[i + 1][j] = get_randltr(a[i][j]);
a[i + 2][j] = get_randltr(a[i][j]);
ini=1;
}
if (a[i][j] == a[i][j+1] && a[i][j+1] == a[i][j+2]) 
{
a[i][j + 1] = get_randltr(a[i][j]);
a[i][j + 2] = get_randltr(a[i][j]);
ini=1;
}
else
ini=0;
}
}
}
}while(ini);
}

void initialize(char a[8][8])
{
int i, j;
int ini;

ini=0;
do {
for (i = 1; i < 7; i++) 
{
for (j = 1; j < 7; j++)
{
if (a[i][j] == a[i-1][j] && a[i-1][j] == a[i-2][j]) 
{
a[i - 1][j] = get_randltr(a[i][j]);
a[i - 2][j] = get_randltr(a[i][j]);
ini=1;
}
if (a[i][j] == a[i+1][j] && a[i+1][j] == a[i+2][j]) 
{
a[i + 1][j] = get_randltr(a[i][j]);
a[i + 2][j] = get_randltr(a[i][j]);
ini=1;
}
if (a[i][j] == a[i][j-1] && a[i][j-1] == a[i][j-2]) 
{
a[i][j - 1] = get_randltr(a[i][j]);
a[i][j - 2] = get_randltr(a[i][j]);
ini=1;
}
if (a[i][j] == a[i][j+1] && a[i][j+1] == a[i][j+2]) 
{
a[i][j + 1] = get_randltr(a[i][j]);
a[i][j + 2] = get_randltr(a[i][j]);
ini=1;
}
else
ini=0;
}
}
}while(ini);
}

void pulling(char b[6][6])
{
int rowc, i, colc,empty,temp;

for(colc = 0; colc < 5; colc++)
{    
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) 
{    
for (rowc = 0; rowc < 5; rowc++)
{
empty = b[rowc][colc]; 

if (empty != '*')
{  
if(b[rowc+1][colc] == '*')
{
temp = b[rowc][colc];
b[rowc][colc] = b[rowc+1][colc];
b[rowc+1][colc] = temp;

} 
}
}

}

}
for (rowc=0; rowc<6; rowc++)
{
for (colc=0; colc<6; colc++)
{
if(b[rowc][colc] == '*')
{
b[rowc][colc] = rand()%4 + 'A';
nomatch(b);
}
}
}
}
```